# How do i add vertical scroll bar in asp Dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFrom" runat="server" CssClass="From"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and my css code is `.From{ width:250px;height:25px}`

Height can not be so large because there are large number of items in it.
How do I add a vertical scroll bar to my drop down ?

Comment: What about "overflow-y: scroll" in your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few 3rd party controls out there in the web, and you could easily bing them. I just put a very simple workaround that involves DropDownExtender (of AJAX ControlToolkit), TextBox, ListBox, and a few lines of Javascript.

Here TextBox will hold the selected value of the listbox. My ASPX code below:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Select your item" CssClass="MyTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
            <div style="padding: 4px;" id="ItemsDiv" runat="server">
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" onclick="callme()" CssClass="MyDropDown" Rows="6">
                </asp:ListBox>
            </div>
            <asp:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
                DropDownControlID="ItemsDiv">
            </asp:DropDownExtender>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<script>
   function callme() { 
           element = document.getElementById("ListBox1"); 
            str = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value; 
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = str; 
        } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Remove the height of the dropdown so that it will grow automatic

Option 2. If it is in a table cell or something which does not allow it to grow then put it in a div like below

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:50px;
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;">
<select....></select>
</div>
```

Here are some example [click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12872/Horizontal-scroll-bar-in-a-combo-box-or-a-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

In the css class add `overflow-y:auto`, when the options length increases beyon 25px, you will get a scrollbar in y-axis of your dropdpwn

Comment: i have tried overflow:auto but it does not any effect on dropdown