# How to add scroll bar on dropdownlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlistfor

I  have tried to add a scroll bar on dropdownlist but it not working perfect how i can add a scroll bar?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Inventory_No_dropdown" 
                  runat="server" 
                  Font-Bold="true"
                  onmousedown="this.size=5;" 
                  onfocusout="this.size=1;" 
                  ondblclick="this.size=1;" 
                  class=""  
                  CssClass="span3" 
                  Style="position: absolute !important;"
                  AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                  AutoPostBack="True" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="Inventory_No_dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem  Value="0" >--------SELECT--------</asp:ListItem>

 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i add vertical scroll bar in asp Dropdown list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516449/how-do-i-add-vertical-scroll-bar-in-asp-dropdown-list)

Comment: i dont have a kit for dropdownextender here its use dropdownextender but i want to use simple asp.net dropdownlist

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2011/05/02/dropdownlist-html-select-vertical-scrollbar-number-of-items.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Inventory_No_dropdown" 
                  runat="server" 
                  Font-Bold="true"
                  onmousedown="this.size=5;" 
                  onfocusout="this.size=1;" 
                  ondblclick="this.size=1;" 
                  class=""  
                  CssClass="span3 dropmenuScroll" //or  CssClass="dropmenuScroll"
                  Style="position: absolute !important;"
                  AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                  AutoPostBack="True" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="Inventory_No_dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem  Value="0" >--------SELECT--------</asp:ListItem>

 </asp:DropDownList>
```

css style

```
.dropmenuScroll
{
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks its work for me but onclick same satuation occur i use ondblclick thats why but why onclick not working.